# Feedback on Implementing Merkle Airdrop for Rug Pull Victims

Tags: testing, dao, airdrop, merkleization, merkle

**Summary**: Developed a smart contract that enables the GovernorDAO Community to un-rug the CBDAO Rug Pull victims by providing them with a Merkle Distribution Airdrop. Over 1/3 of an already-minted supply of tokens are on the line ($2M value) and I have been tasked with covering the Airdrop (after a developer promised to do so and caught COVID and hasn't been heard from).

**Design Specifications**: an airdrop to over 3K recipients where claims may be made at a rate of 10% of the eligible amount with an additional 1% available each day until 90 days have elapsed (100%). For each claim < 100%, the forfeited amount is split thusly, 50% burned, 50% rewards pool. *Note: the rewards pool is shared amongst those who waited the full 90 days to claim.*

**Design Specifications: Summary**

- N of(Recipients, Amount): 3,716
- Available on Day 1: 10% of Amount
- Daily Reward Available: 1% of Amount
- Day 90: 100% Available
- Day 100: Airdrop Claiming Terminates

**Progress**: Smart Contract is 95% complete and may be found [here](https://github.com/CryptoUnico/merkle-distributor). Pre-configured tests from the original Uniswap Repo passes with MerkleDistributor.sol updates, but it fails when an attempt to move funds anywhere other than account or deployer.

**Assistance Requested**: (1) An explanation as to how to create the Merkle Root that is referenced in the smart contract and deploy on the blockchain. (2) Assurance that only the *account* may request a claim and such claims cannot be made *on behalf* of another (to avoid malicious claims). (3) Logic and bug testing from any devs willing and able to try to break it.

**Claims Code Snippet**

```
// SET CLAIM AND SEND FUNDS.
_setClaimed(index);

// TIME SETTINGS
// [P] Start (unix): 1607990400 | Tuesday, December 15th, 2020 @ 12:00AM GMT
uint256 startTime = 1607495500;
// [P] End (unix): 1616630400 | Thursday, March 25th, 2021 @ 12:00AM GMT
uint256 endTime = 1616630400;

// CLAIMS PERIOD   
uint256 nowTime = block.timestamp;
uint256 duraTime = nowTime - startTime;
require(nowTime >= startTime, 'MerkleDistributor: Too soon');
require(nowTime <= endTime, 'MerkleDistributor: Too late');

// MAX TIME
uint256 duraDays = duraTime / 86400 >= 90 ? 90 : duraTime / 86400; // divided by the number of seconds per day
require(duraDays <= 100, 'MerkleDistributor: Too late'); // double check days

// AVAILABILITY CALCULATION    
uint256 availAmount = amount * (10 + duraDays) / 100;// 10% + 1% daily
require(availAmount <= amount, 'MerkleDistributor: Slow your roll');// do not over-distribute
uint256 forfeitedAmount = amount - availAmount;

// ACCOUNT TRANSFERS
require(IERC20(token).transfer(account, availAmount), 'MerkleDistributor: Transfer to Account failed.');
// [P] Update: include 50% transfer to rewardsPool and 50% burn | 50% of 'forfeitedAmount'
require(IERC20(token).transfer(rewardsPool, forfeitedAmount), 'MerkleDistributor: Transfer to Deployer failed.');
```

Comment: Did you try creating a bounty in gitcoin.co?

Comment: @Ismael le no. it’s a simple ask. it’s already complete, just wanted a second pair of eyes. I am not even on the distribution list and I have worked for free thus far, so I have nothing to offer beyond reciprocating the favor now or in the future.

Comment: If you have a specific problem it is better to ask directly. I see code snippets but it is hard to make any assertion without context, and reading the whole project is too much effort without a concrete problem in mind.

Comment: Currently, I am trouble determining what to input as the merkleProof under the claim write function when interacting with the contract on Etherscan that I deployed on Rinkeby.

Comment: Figured it out. Was using the wrong Merkle Root after switching up the claims data. Silly mistake.